# Delphi create button with image

Tags: class, delphi, delphi-xe7

I have problem with creating button with Image and Label inside it.
Here my code:

Class:

```
  type
  Folder = class(TButton)
    AName:TLabel;
    AImage:TImage;
    constructor Create(Nme:String;Path:String;Handle:TForm);
  end;
```

Constructor:

```
constructor Folder.Create(Nme:String;Path:String;Handle:TForm);
begin
  AImage:=Timage.Create(Self);
  AName:=TLabel.Create(Self);
  AImage.Parent:=Self;
  AName.Parent:=Self;
  AName.Caption:=Nme;
  AImage.Picture.LoadFromFile(Path);
end;`
```

And event where I create this button:

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var Fld:Folder;
  begin
  Fld:=Folder.Create('It','D:\image.bmp',Form3);
  Fld.Parent:=Form3;
  Fld.Width:=100;
  Fld.Height:=100;
end;
```

But when I'm creating this button it causes acess violation!What I must to do with it?

Comment: I would suggest you first go read up on inheritance, overriding of methods, "reintroduce" and deriving from Custom controls. For example; you did not reintroduce your constructor and you did not inherit from any ancestor constructor. Have a look at: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Component_Writer's_Guide_Index. A hint; when you create a component that is derived from a specific ancestor then it is advisable to keep to the structure of that ancestor and adjust accordingly.

Comment: Buttons support images already

Comment: Little side note: class name should begin with T, field names with 'f', while arguments with 'a', to avoid confusion. Also, 'Handle' argument is not used in your constructor.

Comment: another advice: activate "generation of debug information" for your project so you can see the stack trace

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Problem:

The problem is that you have declared a customized version of constructor, but you are not calling the parent constructor of `TButton` class.

You need to change the constructor like this:

```
constructor Folder.Create(Nme: String; Path: String; Handle: TForm);
begin
  inherited Create(Handle);     // <- Add this line
  AImage := TImage.Create(Self);
  AName := TLabel.Create(Self);
  AImage.Parent := Self;
  AName.Parent := Self;
  AName.Caption := Nme;
  AImage.Picture.LoadFromFile(Path);
end;
```

#### General advice:

You need to learn how to debug such problems yourself.

Put a breakpoint on line `Fld:=Folder.Create('It','D:\image.bmp',Form3);` and use `Step Over` <kbd>F8</kbd> / `Trace Into` <kbd>F7</kbd> from `Run` menu to check your code line by line.

You will see that once you reach the line `AImage.Parent:=Self;` the exception occurs. This is because `Self`, which points to your `Folder` object, was not initialized correctly, and is not a proper `TButton` descendant.

You need to learn how to do that to progress any further with Delphi, and you will very soon be able to solve such problems yourself.

---

Also if you need to write a custom component for Delphi, invest some time learning more about the way components work and are being used. I would recommend the following guides on component writing:

> - [Official Component Writer’s Guide](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Component_Writer's_Guide_Index)
> - [Introduction to Component Building by Ray Konopka](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20569)

---

Also consult a guide on [Delphi Coding Style](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10280).

At first glance:

- Class names should begin with `T`
- Class fields should begin with `F` instead of `A`
- `constructor` should be in public section and fields in `private` or `protected`
- You should use spaces around parameters, after variables in declarations and around operators